# Meaning of "This being Canada"

Tags: sentence-meaning

This book's name is "Outliers"

> The explanation for this is quite simple. It has nothing to do with astrology, nor is there anything magical about the first three months of the year. It's simply that in Canada the eligibility cutoff for age-class hockey is January 1. A boy turns ten on January 2, then could be playing alongside someone who doesn't turn ten until the year - and at that age, in pre-adolescence, a twelve-month gap in age represents an enormous difference in physical maturity.
> **This being Canada**, the most hockey-crazed country on earth, coaches start to select players for the traveling "rep" squad-the all-star teams-at the age of nine or ten, and of course they are more-likely to view as talented the bigger and more coordinated players, who have had the benefic of critical extra month of maturity.
> And what happens when a player gets chosen for a red squad? He gets better coaching, and his team-mates are better, and he plays fifty or seventy-five games a season instead of twenty games a season like those left behind in the "house" league, and he practices twice as much as, or even three times more than, he would have otherwise. In the beginning, his advantage isn't so much that he is inherently better but only that he is a little older

What I'm curious about is this.

1. This being Canana(bolded) -> What does it mean? and what clause was reduced to it?

to Astralbee

Thank you for answer, but it doesn't make sense to say "As this is Canada" in bold, so that's why I asked

Comment: First, please replace the image with text. We strive to remain accessible here, and images of text aren't readable by people with text-only readers, such as for the visually impaired. Second, you are asking two unrelated questions in one, which is off-topic for this site. Please choose one question to ask here, remove the image, and type that sentence in. If you REALLY want to ask the other question too, feel free to ask a second question with the "Ask Question" button

Comment: i have modified this question at your request

Comment: "As we are talking about Canada..."

Comment: The subject is "this", not "we"?

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it doesn't make sense to say "As this is Canada" in bold, so that's why I asked

Comment: _This_  here means 'the situation being discussed' - how boys are chosen for top ice-hockey teams in Canada, which is a country extremely keen on ice-hockey.

Comment: @inviolable saying "As this is Canada" in place of the bolded text most definitely *does* make sense

Comment: You've rejected the correct answer in the text of your question. I'm unsure how this question can be answered now.

Comment: Thank all of you for answer